# Initialize on server side

Tags: sails.js, html5-audio, audio-streaming, node-webkit, easyrtc

I have created a Node Webkit application using SailsJS in back-end and AngularJS in front-end. I want to integrate audio-chat in my application using [EasyRTC](https://github.com/priologic/easyrtc). I tried the demo application in my local. And it works fine. I am able to connect two users and do audio-chat. But when I started integrating the same in my application, I was unsuccessful. I could integrate the client-side but not the server-side. Here is my server side code:

```
var http    = require("http");              // http server core module
var express = require("express");           // web framework external module
var io      = require("socket.io");         // web socket external module
var easyrtc = require("easyrtc");           // EasyRTC external module

var httpApp = express();
httpApp.use(express.static(__dirname + "/static/"));
var webServer = server;
// Start Socket.io so it attaches itself to Express server
var socketServer = io.listen(webServer, {"log level":1});
// Start EasyRTC server
var rtc = easyrtc.listen(httpApp, socketServer);
```

I want to integrate this in my Sails code. But I am unable to do it because, when I start the application, the server will be running in `1337` port and I couldn't figure out where to write this code. Can anyone tell me how to fix my problem?

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just looking for the `express` instance that is used by sails.js. You can find that at:

```
sails.hooks.http.app
```

Something like this might be what you want:

```
easyrtc.listen(sails.hooks.http.app, socketServer);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So what should be the socketServer??